# how to enable flavors dynamically in gradle in android

Tags: android, gradle

I use android studio and gradle build my android app.
My app has three build types (debug , test , release ) and more than one hundred flavors .
When I build debug apk by studio or execute any gradle task.The gradle will take about 1 minute in configure step for configuring three hundreds build-variants.
It's terrible.

Is there a way to disable all flavors in develop and enable all flavors only when release in my ci server?

I tried this.

```
project.ext.enableFlavor = project.hasProperty('enableFlavor')
    if(project.ext.enableFalvor){
    android{
        productFlavors {
            wxy {
                manifestPlaceholders = [SCHOOL_URL: "wxy.wqapp.cn", SCHOOL_EDITION: "0"]
        }
        wxy001 {
            manifestPlaceholders = [SCHOOL_URL: "nnu.wqapp.cn", SCHOOL_EDITION: "1"]
        }
        wxy001 {
            manifestPlaceholders = [SCHOOL_URL: "nnu.wqapp.cn", SCHOOL_EDITION: "1"]
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

however , when I exec

```
gradlew clean assemble -PenableFlavor
```

I receives a error:

```
Cannot add task ':wxy:assembleTest' as a task with that name already exists.
```

Who can help me.Thasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my custom build type cann't be named "test" althought no flavor is named "test".
I change the build type "test" to "testp" and then it succeed.